# Scrolling log file (tail -f) animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to create an animation on a website to mimic a scrolling log file or tail -f. I'd feed it a list of fake log messages and they would be written to the bottom of the div and scroll up and off the top as new messages are displayed and then loop around. It needs to look authentic, white on black using a fixed width font etc.

Does anyone know of any javascript or jQuery libraries which could help me with this? I'm a beginner with javascript, so any advice on how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've made a simple example for you

http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/zejCD/1/

```js
// some demo data
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    $("<div />").text("log line " + i).appendTo("#tail")
}

// scroll to bottom on init
tailScroll();

// add button click
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("<div />").text("new line").appendTo("#tail");
    tailScroll();
});

// tail effect
function tailScroll() {
    var height = $("#tail").get(0).scrollHeight;
    $("#tail").animate({
        scrollTop: height
    }, 500);
}
```

```css
#tail {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tail">
    <div>some line of text</div>
</div>

<button>Add Line</button>
```

Comment: please include the solution's essence in the answer, so users won't have to navigate away from the site. also, what if the link invalidates?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a great solution

This uses an ajax request, and the HTTP Range: header to request only the last ~30KB of a log file. It then polls for data appended to that file, and only ever retrieves new data (no refreshing the whole file, or even the last 30KB). Handles file truncation too.

https://github.com/ukhas/js-logtail#readme

Answer (score 2):

I've updated Manuel van Rijn's script to include a timer and a toggle switch, along with some minor changes to the log lines. hope this helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/5rLw3LoL/

html:

```
<div id="tail">
    <div>some line of text</div>
</div>
<button>Add Line</button>
```

js:

```
var tailcounter = 100;
var tailswitch = false;

// scroll to bottom on init
tailScroll();

// add line to log
function tailappend() {
    $("<div />").text("log line " + tailcounter).appendTo("#tail");
    tailcounter++;
    tailScroll();
}

// auto update every second
var t = setInterval(tailappend, 1000);

// toggle updates button click
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (tailswitch) {
        case false:
            clearInterval(t); // turns off auto update
            tailswitch = true;
            alert("auto update off");
            break;
        case true:
            t = setInterval(tailappend, 1000); // restarts auto update
            tailswitch = false;
            alert("auto update on");
            break;
    }
});

// tail effect
function tailScroll() {
    var height = $("#tail").get(0).scrollHeight;
    $("#tail").animate({
        scrollTop: height
    }, 500);
}
```

css: (important for formatting)

```
#tail {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with CSS by simply flipping the outer and inner container using `transform: rotateX(180deg);` https://jsfiddle.net/tnrn6h59/2/

Only issue here is that the scroll is also reversed, not an issue for mobile.

Comment: Best solution I've seen so far because it allows you to scroll up and stay at that location. However, this feature behaves differently in IE 11 and Firefox than in Chrome. In IE and Firefox, if you scroll up, you see content move up as new lines are added which I think is correct behavior. But in Chrome, the content does not move up so you don't know that new content is added if you are not at the bottom of the scrollable area. Any idea how to get Chrome to behave like Firefox / IE?