# How to do `tail -f logfile.txt`-like processing in node.js?

Tags: node.js

`tail -f logfile.txt` outputs the last 10 lines of logfile.txt, and then continues to output appended data as the file grows.

What's the recommended way of doing the `-f` part in node.js?

The following outputs the entire file (ignoring the "show the last 10 lines") and then exits.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rs = fs.createReadStream('logfile.txt', { flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf8'});
rs.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I understand the event-loop is exiting because after the stream end & close event there are no more events -- I'm curious about the best way of continuing to monitor the stream.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224333/scrolling-log-file-tail-f-animation-using-javascript

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is with [`fs.watchFile`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener).

Alternatively, you could just use [the node-tail module](https://github.com/forward/node-tail), which uses `fs.watchFile` internally and has already done the work for you. Here is an example of using it straight from the documentation:

```
Tail = require('tail').Tail;

tail = new Tail("fileToTail");

tail.on("line", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Many thanks -- `fs.watchFile` is exactly what I was looking for. Also thanks for pointing out the node-tail module.

Comment: As of now, `fs.watchFile()` uses stat polling. `fs.watch()` can be used instead, but `fs.stat()` will have to be used to find a file's current and previous size.

Comment: The node-tail module has since been updated to use `fs.watch()`.

Comment: always-tail is better

Comment: Tail module works great! Thank you.

Comment: tail-stream (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail-stream) is also useful for this, and can handle files being moved, truncated etc., like always-tail. It returns an explicit node stream, so can usefully be piped.

Answer (score 8):

[node.js APi documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) on `fs.watchFile` states:

> Stability: 2 - Unstable.  Use fs.watch instead, if available.

Funny though that it says *almost* the exact same thing for `fs.watch`:

> Stability: 2 - Unstable.  Not available on all platforms.

In any case, I went ahead and did yet another small webapp, *TailGate*, that will tail your files using the `fs.watch` variant.

Feel free to check it out here:
[TailGate on github](https://github.com/karlmacklin/TailGate).

Answer (score 4):

you can try to use [`fs.read`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs.read) instead of ReadStream

```
var fs = require('fs')

var buf = new Buffer(16);
buf.fill(0);
function read(fd)
{
    fs.read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, null, function(err, bytesRead, buf1) {
        console.log(buf1.toString());
        if (bytesRead != 0) {
            read(fd);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                read(fd);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }); 
}

fs.open('logfile', 'r', function(err, fd) {
    read(fd);
});
```

Note that read calls callback even if there is no data and it just reached end of file. Without timeout you'll get 100% cpu here. You could try to use `fs.watchFile` to get new data immediately.

Comment: this approach loses some data when log rotate or similar tools are involved

Answer (score 3):

Substack has a [file slice](https://www.npmjs.org/package/slice-file) module that behaves exactly like `tail -f`, slice-file can stream updates after the initial slice of 10 lines.

```
var sf = require('slice-file');

var xs = sf('/var/log/mylogfile.txt');
xs.follow(-10).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Source: https://github.com/substack/slice-file#follow

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jandre/always-tail seems a great option if you have to worry about log rotating, example from the readme:

```
var Tail = require('always-tail');
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = "/tmp/testlog";

if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) fs.writeFileSync(filename, "");

var tail = new Tail(filename, '\n');

tail.on('line', function(data) {
  console.log("got line:", data);
});


tail.on('error', function(data) {
  console.log("error:", data);
});

tail.watch();
```

Comment: always-tail looks like it was abandoned; the last update was in 2015.  See https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail for something more recent.