# Node fs.watch to read changes only

Tags: node.js, logging, fs

`fs.watch('log-file', function(event, filename) {});` only returns the file name that was changed.

Is it possible to only get what was actually changed? I don't want to read the entire file, and rather want to know what was modified from my file (in my case, there is always addition to a log file. nothing ever gets erased).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking to solve a similar problem to [How to do `tail -f logfile.txt`-like processing in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993611/how-to-do-tail-f-logfile-txt-like-processing-in-node-js)

As per the first response I would look into the the [node-tail module](https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail).