# Tail external text file in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to display a text file within an iframe that automatically updates every second. The updating is done in a simple function:

```
function reload() {
    $("#derek").attr('src', $("#derek").attr('src'));
};
```

Then the automatic refreshing is done using `setInterval`:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    reload();
}, 1000);
```

This of course loads the text document so the top is visible and the bottom is cut off. I would like to load the file so the bottom is always visible.

I have tried adding the following in the `reload` function:

```
$d = $("#derek").contents();
$d.scrollTop($d.height());
```

However when the iframe reloads it still loads at the top, then scrolls down, which is a bad effect. Something similar to the answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224333/scrolling-log-file-tail-f-animation-using-javascript) would be ideal.

After opening myself up to using PHP, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290515/live-feed-of-an-updating-file).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Live feed of an updating file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290515/live-feed-of-an-updating-file)

Comment: Having never used WebSockets before, this seems to me like an excellent use case to give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe caused by your typo?

```
d = $("#derek").contents();
d.scrollTop($d.height());
// ----------^
```

should be

```
d = $("#derek").contents();
d.scrollTop(d.height());
// ---------^
```

Comment: Oops. Fixed the typo, thank you. It causes a jittering effect. I presume it's loading from the top and scrolling to the bottom, every second.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to use `setTimeout`

Comment: Yeah, that fixed the flickering. But when the iframe reloads, it will obviously always load at the top of the page, then scroll down. Which looks pretty bad.